# Upper bound for an inverse Laplace transform

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, oc.optimization-and-control, laplace-transform

Can anyone see how to get a tight upper bound for the function defined in terms of the inverse Laplace transform below?
$$g_\text{sgd}(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{5 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{s}}{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}\right)^{-1}\right].$$

Dieter Kadelka's numerical simulation suggests $g_\text{sgd}(t)\approx 0.434 t^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, which appears to model this function very well...where does $O(t^{-\frac{1}{2}})$ form come from?

[image]
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-asymptotic-laplace.nb)

This function describes loss trajectory for stochastic gradient descent (SGD) on a linear least squares problem with  covariance eigenvalues $1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\dotsc$. Expression comes when treating SGD as a continuous time problem which requires solving [a particular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686487/solving-frac-partial-partial-t-f-hf-int-mathrm-d-i-h-f) differential equation

Comment: Looks like $s \to g_{sgd}(s)∗\sqrt s$ is increasing and $\lim_{s \to \infty} g_{sgd}(s)∗\sqrt s$ about 0.433.

Comment: Why do you not calculate $g_{sgd}$ with numerical methods directly, as mentioned in the above link "a particular"? Wolfram Notebook should do it. The resulting function looks similar as that of $g_{gd}$ and in particular $g_{sgd}(0.1)=0.3272708709647729$ and $g_{sgd}(20)=0.095291845071114367$ Is the upper bound for theoretical purposes? (Calculations done with my program).

Comment: Yes, for theoretical purposes. Proving bounds on the limit in your comment would be a very nice result. This would show that SGD stays within a small constant factor of GD for this problem, ie, that it has the same "convergence rate"

Comment: @DieterKadelka btw, the 0.433 constant appears to be $\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{50}}$

Comment: Seems to be correct. I got $g_{gsd}(1e10)*1e5 = 0.434160752718722$. And for $s=1e20$ the difference is $-1.665..10^{-16}$. How did you identify this constant? Very interestingly.

Comment: By the way, $s \to g_{gsd}(s) * \sqrt s$ seems to be concave and increasing from $0$ to $\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{50}}$. If this function is concave indeed then it must be increasing. Concavity may be simpler to show.

Comment: @DieterKadelka I got it by calling Mathematica Asymptotic to get expansion around s=0 . However it's was not clear to me how it decided to use the Puiseux series with the correct leading fractional exponent for this expression

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer. If $g$ is known to be a non-negative function, Karameta Tauberian theorem relates the behavior of $G = \int_0^\cdot g$ at infinity (resp. at 0) to the behavior of $\mathcal{L}g$ at $0$ (resp. at infinity). Reference: William Feller's book *Probability*.

In particular, $G(t) \sim 2ct^{1/2}$ as $t \to \infty$ if and only if $\mathcal{L}g(s) \sim \Gamma(1/2)c s^{-1/2}$ as $s \to 0$.

From $G(t) \sim 2ct^{1/2}$ as $t \to \infty$, one needs regularity assumptions on $g$ to derive $g(t) \sim ct^{-1/2}$ as $t \to \infty$, Assuming that $g$ is non-increasing is sufficient.

Indeed, if $g$ is non-increasing, then for all $r \in~]0,1[$ and $t>0$,
$$\frac{G(t)-G(t-rt)}{rt} \ge g(t) \ge \frac{G(t+rt)-G(t)}{rt}.$$
$$\frac{2ct^{1/2}-2c(t-rt)^{1/2}+O(t^{1/2})}{rt^{1/2}} \ge t^{1/2}g(t) \ge \frac{2c(t+rt)^{1/2}-2ct^{1/2}+O(t^{1/2})}{rt^{1/2}}.$$
$$\frac{2c-2c(1-r)^{1/2}}{r} \ge \limsup_{t \to \infty} t^{1/2}g(t) \ge \liminf_{t \to \infty} t^{1/2}g(t) \ge \frac{2c(1+r)^{1/2}-2c}{r}.$$
Letting $r$ go to $0$ yields
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} t^{1/2}g(t) = c.$$